# How to protect my standalone android app

Tags: android, security, sdk

My android app created by me works completely offline and load some dynamically .jar libraries. Is there a good and effective way to protect applications against copying and distribution of these libraries?

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: use proguard to obfuscate your APK file.

Comment: I discussed about it and using obfuscate is also easy to hack the libs

Answer (score 0):

You can Download to your default package directory.

that directory is private only your application can access that.

You can create folder there and download file at that location.

Comment: I don't think any body have access to that folder